# Puppeteer selector; Button not selected

Tags: javascript, node.js, css-selectors, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to click on `await page.click('.2 tabBtnCenter');`, but it is not working.

Can someone define a proper Puppeteer CSS selector for `value=2 tabBtnCenter`?

```
<div id="headerTab">
    <ul>
        <li value="0">
            <div class="tabBtnLeft"></div>
            <div class="tabBtnCenter">Status</div>
            <div class="tabBtnRight"></div>
        </li>
        <li value="1">
            <div class="tabBtnLeft"></div>
            <div class="tabBtnCenter">WAN</div>
            <div class="tabBtnRight"></div>
        </li>
        <li value="2">
            <div class="tabBtnLeft"></div>
            <div class="tabBtnCenter">LAN</div>
            <div class="tabBtnRight"></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: <div id="headerTab"> 
        <ul><li value="0"><div class="tabBtnLeft"></div><div class="tabBtnCenter">Status</div><div class="tabBtnRight"></div></li><li value="1"><div class="tabBtnLeft"></div><div class="tabBtnCenter">WAN</div><div class="tabBtnRight"></div></li><li value="2"><div class="tabBtnLeft"></div><div class="tabBtnCenter">LAN</div><div class="tabBtnRight"></div></li></ul> 
      </div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following selector to click the element you specified with [`page.click()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageclickselector-options):

```
await page.click('[value="2"] > .tabBtnCenter');
```

Comment: await page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'load'});

    await page.click( '[value="2"] > .tabBtnCenter' );

Comment: Plus do share any links from which i can understand the key concepts of selectors

Comment: @FaizanAwan Here's a great resource for learning more about CSS selectors: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Using [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) :

```
const sel = await page.$x("//div[text()='LAN' and @class='tabBtnCenter']");

if (sel.length > 0) {
    await sel[0].click();
}
else {
    throw new Error("selector not found");
}
```